# Copy/paste into SSH'd VIM from local (Windows) clipboard

Tags: ssh, vim, copy-paste

I would like to copy from a local machine and paste into vim on a remote box which I am SSH'd into.

That's it.

I have tried `"+p and "*p`, mouse middle-clicking, and a couple other things to no avail :(

Also acceptable (though less convenient) is to just skip vim and pipe clipboard into file.

My problem was that I am using PuttyTray and not Putty, when I tried to do the same thing in Putty it worked -- I didn't think there would be a problem with that.

Comment: Are you in insert mode for `vi`? Using `putty`? Try shift+insert.

Comment: shift+insert and then what? yes, putty

Comment: Putty should have the standard clipboard facilities (copy, paste, cut...) somewhere in the window menu - have you tried that? Remember to have `vi` in insert mode when you do that as jordanm suggested. It is also usually a good idea to `:set paste` when pasting anything into `vim`. Also check PuTTY's selection options: configuration -> Window -> Selection (see e.g. http://www.codeweblog.com/upload/c/h/change-english-tutorial-wonderful-putty_13.png)

Comment: Why did Microsoft do such a poor job integrating ssh into its system?  It's a stick in the eye to all of us who log into servers to do work.

Answer (score 37):

On my windows laptop, pasting into remote `vim`, this is the only thing I could get to work:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> was fine for copying.. but I needed
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to Paste !

(A good reason to get a laptop where <kbd>Insert</kbd> can  be accessed without pressing a secondary key)

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me?

Comment: @Grayscale manufacturers can configure Windows machines in various ways, so there is less consistency than Mac's. Sometimes the `Fn` key must also be pressed in order to enable the `Insert` functionality on that key. Or maybe another combination works. Fortunately, in the latest versions of Win 10, standard methods, such as menus from a mouse right click, works now, in many places it previously did not.

Comment: In the case that a secondary key is redwood to access the `Insert` functionality, *sometimes* the manufacturer will provide a way to swap out which set of function key functionality is default, and which requires the `fn` key. I don't remember the details, but one laptop I had allow me to change the default. I think it was in the boot menu? I don't think is was bios. Anyway, it wasn't an obvious, often accessed location, but once I saw the documentation online, it was super easy to do.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

1. Right click in command prompt window's title area.
2. Click "Properties".
3. In "Options" > "Edit Options", click the checkbox next to "Use Ctrl+Shift+C/V as Copy/Paste".

Answer (score 5):

If you are using windows 10 ssh on the command line all you need to do is right-click the mouse.

Comment: Right-click has [already been mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526054/117549)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: For me right click enters visual mode and does nothing to copy

Comment: This worked for me, but having to switch to mouse to paste is a little inconvenient (mouse drag + Ctrl-C works though). Was hoping there would be a keyboard shortcut that would work for pasting. The others I tried didn't work, eg Shift-Ins just inserts raw text into Vim. On my Windows 10 machine (processor too old to upgrade), this is a problem, but using the Terminal in Windows 11 running PowerShell, I don't have the same issue and can just Ctrl-C/V.

Answer (score 4):

Enter insert mode in vim (i) and you can right click on the putty window to bring up a menu that has a paste command. Also an option in the menu bar. Works for me from windows.

Putty doesn't copy the the contents of the windows clipboard to the remote computer's clipboard. It basically virtually enters them as if you were typing the characters in the clipboard.

Comment: when I ctrl+right click the paste button is grayed out! (and just right click doesn't do anything).

Comment: @frickskit are you sure the text you want to paste is in the clipboard? Try pasting it in notepad to be sure. This always worked for me.

Comment: My problem is that I am using PuttyTray and not Putty, when I tried to do the same thing in Putty it worked -- I didn't think there would be a problem with that.

Comment: @frickskit ah... You said putty earlier... I'm not familiar with PuttyTray

Comment: yeah, my bad -- didn't think they would be different.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the Windows Subsystem for Linux to SSH and could not get anything to work for pasting into Vim directly (including right-click). Pasting into the terminal outside of vim did work though (with right-click), so I ended up just doing

```
echo "<right-click to paste>" >> filename.txt
```

then `vim filename.txt` and putting the pasted text where I wanted it. Annoying, but better than nothing at least...

Answer (score 2):

Hold `shift` while pressing `right-click` to paste into `vim` from `powershell` over an `ssh` connection.

Answer (score 1):

These days, I am using WSL (Ubuntu 18 TLS) in a Windows 10 machine instead of PuTTY for SSH and I use Vim.

I had troubles copying code from Windows 10 to paste in the remote server.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> did not work or any other method.

My solution is: copy text from a window, then move to the Ubuntu terminal, then change Vim to insert mode (insert) then use the right click of the mouse.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+V did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

### From my windows computer, I connect with Putty to 2 different machines:

1. Machine: Ubuntu system; pasting with mouse-right-click into Putty window

   - OK: works at linux console
   - OK: works at VIM editor
2. Machine: firewall system with a basic linux system; pasting with mouse-right-click into Putty window

   - OK: works at linux console
   - FAILED: doesn't work at VIM editor

     - if I am at mode `-- INSERT --`, after mouse right click the VIM is in mode `-- VISUAL --`
     - so it might be a "feature" somehow that we all didn't expected and don't want?!
   - OK: `Shift`+`Insert` works

### My conclusion for now: it's

- not a client setting thing, because it's depending on the remote server that I connect to
- not a Putty application thing, because it's both times the same software
- not a Putty configuration thing, because I use the same session configuration for both remote servers (changing the Putty session options didn't worked for me)
- a remote server thing, that VIM is either

  - configured differently between distros or
  - a special package is required to be installed and enabled and the distros provide a different set of installed packages

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however, that in the current form your post looks like an error analysis, which is off-topic on this site, where the idea is to have one question and one or more "definitive" solutions. Please revise your post in case it was intended as a full-fledged answer to prevent this kind of misunderstanding, or add the key content as a comment to the question rathern than posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this post has already been answered, but as a further option; I use PuTTy and my local machine is Windows 10.

If I copy some text from my local machine, all I need to do is to right mouse click into the PuTTy terminal window, and this will paste my clipboard there.

It doesn't matter if you are using `vim`, `vi` or `nano`, etc. it will still work, as this is a PuTTy terminal.

Comment: Right-click has [already been mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526054/117549)

Comment: Thanks @JeffSchaller, I know, hence why I said in the beginning of my post. I mentioned it because it wasn't explicitly made clear to anyone in detail :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do.

Inside of Linux SSH session:
type `cat nameoffile`
highlight text with mouse, right click it and select copy.

Then on Windows application such as Word:
Right click and select paste.

Comment: I think you read the question backwards :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that `set mouse=n` allowed me to still click my mouse inside of nvim, but also pastes from an ssh terminal into the machine running vim.