# vim: shift+insert works for external keyboard but not laptop keyboard

Tags: vim

I'm very new to linux and vim, my laptop computer is windows and I'm using ssh to access my school's unbuntu linux in the terminal. The funny thing is, when I use shift+insert through external keyboard to paste from clipboard(in vim), things works very well. However the laptop keyboard fails.

I solved the copy/paste problem by changing the options of terminal( https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600067), but the keyboard thing is still confusing me, just don't know why would it happen.

Comment: Does the Ins key require a Func key or similar Shift-like key to be held down? It's not uncommon for keyboards with less than the usual 104-ish keys to do stuff like that....e.g. i've got one that requires Func + Up-Arrow for PgUp, so Shift-PgUp requires Shift+Func+Up-Arrow.

Comment: Welcome to this site, and I hope will will be of good use for you, but I'm afraid it's the wrong site for this question, because neither the remote linux machine nor vim don't know anything about what keyboard you are using. According to your question it's your MS Windows machine producing different key codes depending on the keyboard you use.

Comment: Thanks cas and Philippos. @cas The shift+insert does not need a function key, I tried shift+insert at some where else and it worked.

Comment: @Philippos got it, thanks.